# A weird optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've the following optimization problem:$$\max f(R,z)=R^2(a+z)$$$$\operatorname{sub}\begin{cases}R^2+z^2=a^2\\0\le z \le a\end{cases}$$
Once solved it gives $z=a/3$,  ...

Consider now the optimization problem: $$\max f(R,z)=R(a+z)$$$$\operatorname{sub}\begin{cases}R^2+z^2=a^2\\0\le z \le a \\R\ge 0\end{cases}$$

whose solutions are $z=a/2$, ...

My question is: why does the latter problem differ from the first problem, that is why don't they give the same solutions?

Comment: i dont abt the answer, but really like ur username, same here,love math :)

Answer (score 2):

The second doesn't have $R$ squared in the objective, so doesn't "feel the same pull" to make $R$ large.

If we set $a$ to $1$ (which just sets the scale) and use your constraint, the first objective is $(1-z^2)(1+z)$ while the second is $\sqrt{1-z^2}(1+z)$  [This Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%5B%281-x%5E2%29%281%2Bx%29%20%2Csqrt%20%281-x%5E2%29%281%2Bx%29%5D%20from%200%20to%201) shows the comparison.  The red curve has the square root, so pulls the maximum for $z$ higher.

[image]

Comment: The more $R$ is bigger, the more $f$ is larger...so it should be the same for the first problem

Comment: I really can't figure it out

Comment: But the same can be said of $z$: the larger $z$ is, the larger the objective is. Since you're trading off between $R$ and $z$, putting less "incentive" on $R$ encourages you to make $z$ larger.

Comment: oh God you're right